# Materialize - Select multiple value

Tags: jquery, materialize

When i use *Materialize Multiple select*, i get the values on log with.

html:

```
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm">

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-field">
        <select multiple class="validate" id="pregunta_c1"
            name="pregunta_c1[]">
            <option value="" disabled selected>-</option>
            <option value="0">option1</option>
            <option value="1">option2</option>
            <option value="2">option3</option>
            <option value="3">option4</option>
            <option value="4">option5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

script:

```
var formData = new FormData($("#contactForm")[0]);
var ask1 = $('#pregunta_c1').val();

alert(ask1); 
console.log(ask1);
```

Console output:

```
alert =  1,2,3;
console = ["1", "2", "3"];
Formdata = 3;
```

I am sending the form whit `formData` and this only get the last selected option. I just try many ways but just keeps getting the last option. no an array of the select.

There is some way of send the form by `formData` and get the array with materialize ?

Comment: Could you share your complete script? I can't reproduce the error (it works fine to me).

Comment: i just did // 
 var pregunta_c1 = $('#pregunta_c1').val();
 formData.append("pregunta_c1",pregunta_c1 ); //
and it works.